# CertBot unauthorized - Invalid response

Tags: amazon-web-services, lets-encrypt, certbot

Am trying to install a certificate for my webapp, which is deployed in my Amazon AWS.

```
 ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 -d www.mywebsite.com --debug
```

when I run the above command, I get the following response

```
 The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.mywebsite.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.mywebsite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/PoX30b9dlmVuf-iU6zcNOo7_l7FaYTiJMgjHR4td8p4:
   "<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.70 - Error
   report</title><style><!--H1
   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;bac"
```

Am trying to point to the app which I deployed in `Apache tomcat server`. I could see the `.well-known` folder is getting created but the folder is completely empty.

Any Light on this?

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that you standalone server didn't bind to the required IP/port. That's why the error message contains response from Tomcat. You shold **stop your Tomcat server**, then run `certbot-auto --standalone`, so certbot's build-in webserver could serve responses.

Comment: The localmachine tomcat is off , that why its running. The apache error what you see is the response from the actual domain

Comment: Well, yes. Certificate Authority **will contact your actual domain**. How else should it verify that you own that domain? Your domain should point to the server, where you're executing `certbot`.

Comment: The domain is pointing to the server through Amazon elastic IP.

Comment: If the domain name is pointing to the same server where you're running certbot, you didn't stop Tomcat.

Comment: in my localmachine Thats why am using --standalone

Comment: @madhairsilence to reiterate... with `--standalone`, you still have to run this on the *actual web site server itself.*  That is the point -- the service needs to confirm that you control the actual web site. Using `--standalone` doesn't mean "from somewhere else" -- it means "I'm on the web server machine and the web server service is stopped."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeh. What about --manual. Where I can install manualy. I face the same problem again

Comment: http://www.mywebsite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/PoX30b9dlmVuf-iU6zcNOo7_l7FaYTiJMgjHR4td8p4:.. This returns 404 always

Answer (score 0):

First of all do a sudo su -
It will only work if you are using root as user.

now create a file /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini
and add

```
rsa-key-size = 4096
email = example@mail.com
```

then run

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos
```

and after that add to crontab

```
0 1 1 * * /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos && apachectl graceful
```